(R) Automating scatterplots from massive excel file
For R
I have a massive excel file that I would like to create scatterplots from. My x-axis would remain the same throughout this process (a column in the excel of a list of peoples ages corresponding to their volume value of a brain region) but my y value would need to run through columns of data in the excel (all of the brain regions)
Being that there are so many columns of these regions how might I automate this process most efficiently?
Thank you.
I am still very novice and need some guidance. I attempted a for loop with a breakdown of the column names into a data frame and plugged that in, but the plots looks abnormal - they were all in one straight line. I don’t think it plotted the actual data in the columns, just the column name.

What is preventing you from doing this entirely inside Excel? Its scatter plots are a bit fussy about every column having a name but they are there and do work. It also doesnt' like having too many columns at once (but you can alter the data size once it has plotted an XY graph). Only other thing to watch is doing it from VBA is that in some versions there are race conditions where it can try to plot data before the axes are fully defined (small delay fixes that). One symptom of that is that some points don't end up where they should be on the graph. Also how massive is massive?

I am going to run more than scatterplots in the overall analysis,
Massive here means roughly 120x130. I acknowledge I may have unintentionally exaggerated what massive means for this. Again, I’m new.
Ultimate goal is to get this completely ran through R.
For this case, here’s a bit more detail. In my column A I have “Subject ID” and then a bunch of rows of identifiers, then “Group” where I’ll sort by diagnoses, “Age” is next, and then the remaining are all the brain region volumes - want to look at linear regression too. Maybe I should reformat the excel? Would that help?

That size isn't massive although it probably is enough to fox Excel unless you first create the XY scatter graph 100x10 and then extend the data range. Working out what you want to plot and looking for a way to present it is going to be more than half the battle. Unless you are going to do it many times for several large datasets I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency - concentrate on correctness first and finding the interesting data correlations second. Efficiency can come later if it is actually needed.

Here's a simple example
library(tidyverse)

# make a fake dataset
df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(0:120, 100, replace = TRUE),
  cerebrum = sample(1300:1500, 100, replace = TRUE),
  cerebellum = sample(100:150, 100, replace = TRUE),
  brainstem = sample(15:35, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

#transform the data into long format and plot it
df %>%  
  # create a dataframe with the columns age, region, volume
  pivot_longer(cols = -age, names_to = "region", values_to = "volume") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = volume, color = region)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  # show one plot per region
  facet_wrap(~region)

